# How to select all fields but show certain in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagridview

I am showing some data on DataGridView in c# windows form App. Here I want to select ID because I have to use it as foreign key but I don't want to show that ID field on grid.

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from PatientInfo", con))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(reader);
                        datagridpatient.DataSource = dt;
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to show just name, email, phone. At the same time for further use I need to select ID too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide the column,

dataGridView.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;

Ex:

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
         {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from PatientInfo", con))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(reader);
                        datagridpatient.DataSource = dt;
                        if (datagridpatient.Columns.Contains("ID")
                           datagridpatient.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Bang-on.. Thanks pal

Comment: Edited my answer with validating the connection status @SidraM.